# Pulling Information out of Bibfile

Tags: biblatex

I would like to organize the papers I've read in the way outlined here https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10578/how-to-read-and-take-notes-on-research-papers/10616#10616.

But it kind of annoys me to write out author and year and things like that, which are already in my global bib-file (or should be). Also, I would like mistakes corrected everywhere if I correct them in the bib-file. Is there a way to get at the information from the bib-file for my latex-document?

So, instead of: (shamelessly copied from above post)

```
\section{Paper #1 Name, Authors, Date, \cite{...}}
My summary of the motivation and findings of the paper, or whatever I find interesting.
May be as short as a few sentences or as long as a page, depending on how relevant it is. 
\index{an important word}
```

I would want to write something like:

```
\section{\mycitetitle{citekeyfrombibfile}}
\citeurl{citekeyfrombibfile}
notes and so on
```

where `\mycitetitle` would expand to Title, Authors, Year and `\citeurl` would expand to the url (if available). I guess this would be a case for biblatex, but I am just starting with that and not yet sure what it can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `biblatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
  author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1994},
  url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepaper}[\section]
  {}
  {\bibyhyperref{Paper 
     \printfield{title}, 
     \printnames{author}, 
     \printfield{year} 
     \mkbibbrackets{\printfield{labelnumber}}}}
  {}
  {}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citepaper{Goossens1994LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

The solution implements a new cite command (`\citepaper`) printing the desired/required information.

[image]

Comment: Will this be clickable? I mean, can I click on it and it gives me the reference at the end of the file like the usual cite-command? (If I decide to have a bibliography at the end of the file) Does this give me an entry in the bibliography? And is there a way to make it flexible on whether it is a section or a subsection? That would be useful sometimes, although I guess I could just declare two separate commands.

Comment: updated the solution to include clickable hyperlinks

Comment: hm, the version with `bibhyperref` gives me `Unknown command \citepaper`, also it was fine without. Does this depend on the version of biblatex?

Comment: You have to use `\citepaper` also in `\DeclareCiteCommand`)

Comment: I just noticed there was a typo. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Late to the party, but the solution isnt working for me. I copy/pasted it directly into Overleaf and I get a "Undefined control sequence.
\blx@loopcode ->\bibyhyperref" error, which I dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `bibentry`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib1.bib}
@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
  author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
  title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1994{.}},
  url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\nobibliography{mybib1}

\subsection*{\bibentry{Goossens1994LaTeX}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be dumping just everything, which might get ugly for some of my bib-file entries.

Comment: @fifaltra It is supposed to do that :-) Please ask a new question on how to modify the output of `\bibentry` so as to get specific content.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, an alternative method I have found while waiting for answers is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Goossens1994LaTeX,
 author = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
 title = {The \LaTeX{} Companion, $2^{nd}$ Edition},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 year = {1994},
 url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\mytitlecite}[1]
 {\texorpdfstring{\citetitle{#1}, \citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1},\cite{#1}}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section{\href{file.pdf}{Paper} \mytitlecite{Goossens1994LaTeX}}

\end{document}
```

Where file.pdf is the file containing the paper on the local file system. This also avoids warnings from hyperref. The other [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208210/39366) could be extended to do that however, and has the extra feature that the whole section title is clickable, not just the label.